# Possible to re-instate the 'Recurring' payment in paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is this possibe to Re-instate the recurring payment option using same

> 'PROFILE ID'

...That was previously cancelled in paypal.

API - paypal Express checkout

Thankz in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to reinstate (activate) the canceled recurring profile. Create a new recurring profile for a recurring payment. If the recurring profile is in the suspended state then you can re-activate it.